# White space before text in input

Tags: html, css

Good morning,

I have a little problem i have a text input field with border radius and because of the border radius the first character that is typed kind of sticks out the input field how can i fix this? like a little bit of whitespace extra before the first character.

HTML

```
<label for="u_name">Gebruikersnaam</label>
<input type="text" name="u_name" value="">
```

CSS

```
input[type=text], [type=email], [type=password] {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Maantje I would recommend you to use `box-sizing: border-box` with the `padding-left` - [good article about `box-sizing`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you simply have to add padding to your input and change its width according to padding size (`box-sizing`, as @[Vucko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763929/vucko) said could do the trick, but IE8 doesn't support it).

```css
input[type=text], [type=email], [type=password]{
  width: 284px; /* this width is your initial width - padding-left - padding-right; */
  padding:0 8px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="u_name">Gebruikersnaam</label>
<input type="text" name="u_name" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `text-indent: 5px`:

```css
input[type=text], [type=email], [type=password] {
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: 5px;/*add text-indent*/
    outline: none;/*also remove outline*/
}
```

```html
<label for="u_name">Gebruikersnaam</label>
<input type="text" name="u_name" value="">
```

Also remove outline.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the style of the padding-left to 0

Comment: `padding-left: 0` won't do what the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding-left to your input, check the fiddle.

```
padding-left: 10px;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y0172cg4/)